# Area between two curves measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

How do I show that for $f,g\in C[a,b]$ the set $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:a\leq x\leq b, f(x)\leq y\leq g(x)\}$ is Lebesgue-measurable?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1437110/307169

Answer (score 1):

Since $f $ and $g $ are continuous, $A $ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2,$ which gives the assertion.